# How did early metalsmiths devise tools?

Tags: prehistory, historical-techniques, metallurgy

As I understand it, the refining of ore requires, at at least one point, the direct handling of high-temperature or molten metal. I can see early coppersmiths beating stone hammers on flat rocks, but how did they make more sophisticated metal tools, like tongs, vises, rasps, punches, or nails that would in turn allow the creation of more complex implements and facilitate later metals?

Comment: What research have you already conducted into this (to prevent people covering the same ground) ?

Comment: Early metalsmiths did not make tongs, rasps etc.  neither use them. Some basic research would indeed help to improve the question. Even in Youtube you can find several videos showing different smelting, melting etc techniques from ancient times and middle ages.